# How do I program Python so that it outputs to all terminals in Linux

Tags: linux, python

I am programming a python program for the raspberry pi.
Is there a way for me so that when the raspberry pi outputs text, it will show up on all terminals that are currently remotely logged in via SSH?

Comment: I migrated this here instead of S.O. because, although it involves programming, I think this particular question will get better answers here.

Comment: Can you install [tmux](http://tmux.github.io/) or [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)? Both can run a session in the background and you can just connect to (or disconnect from) it when needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use the `wall` program, but the logged in users may be able to override that and avoid seeing any `wall` messages. Alternately, you can attempt configure and use syslog to send a message from a given facility to the `*` location, which (in my experience) will show up on all logged in shells.

Comment: Using a syslog interface (I presume python has one) with sufficient priority ("emergency") should get the output posted everywhere including `ssh` logins on most systems by default (you shouldn't have to configure syslog) -- and it seems you don't even need special privileges to do so...

Comment: You *shouldn't* have to configure syslog, no, but there's no guarantee that syslog will have a default configuration or a sufficient configuration for this. I myself tend to disable the "emergency" syslog spam on all my systems - if I don't know about an emergency without syslog telling me about it, I have bigger problems.

Comment: The fact that this method is dependent on syslog configuration is indeed important.  Its advantage over writing directly to the tty's/pty's is that you can target everyone without needing root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

In a very simplistic way: you can look at all the **pseudo-ttys** in use
and write to all of them. Use `who` to list all the current logins and
their tty, eg:

```
$ who
me       tty1         Jun  1 07:09
brian    pts/0        Jun  1 07:15 (:pc1)
john     pts/1        Jun  1 07:15 (:pc88)
sue      pts/2        Jun  1 07:15 (:pc7)
```

The 2nd column shows e.g. `/dev/pts/0` is being used by login `brian`.  You can simply write to it, if you have sufficient permission, eg:

```
echo 'Msg from me: hello!' >/dev/pts/0
```

On my system (not a pi, sorry), you need to be in group tty, or be root:

```
$ ls -l /dev/pts/0
crw--w---- 1 brian tty 136, 4 Jun 28 20:55 /dev/pts/0
```